# CMAKE override variable set in CMakeLists.txt via commandline

Tags: cmake

I have a CMakeLists.txt with the following in it, that I **can not modify**:

```
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
```

I want to override this variable use the commandline. I tried this:

```
cmake -UBUILD_SHARED_LIBS -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
```

but it has no effect. Is there any way to tell cmake to use a value from the commandline instead of this value?

Note: I am aware that using the cache like shown below would solve the problem, but as I cannot edit the file, that sadly is not an option:

```
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON CACHE BOOL "library build mode")
```

Comment: Is this the only CMake file you can **not** modify? Can you modify other CMakeLists.txt files in your project, perhaps ones where `add_library()` is called?

Comment: @squareskittles Sadly no, the whole project is pulled in as a git submodule. As a workaround, I now use `sed` to replace the line before building and revert afterwards...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using command line you **cannot** **override** setting of the **normal** (non-cached) **variable**.

---

If you pass a variable via command line, then it is always a cache variable. At the time when normal flavor of the variable is set in the `CMakeLists.txt`, **both flavors** exist. But when a variable is dereferenced, CMake prefers normal flavor to the cached one. See more in the [variables' documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variables).